# How Can I Concat 2 SelectList lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to combine 2 SelectLists into one, Concat() wants a cast that I can't figure out.

```
SelectList sl1 = new SelectList(Cust.GetCustListOne(), "Id", "Last", 2);
SelectList sl2 = new SelectList(Cust.GetCustListTwo(), "Id", "Last", 4);
SelectList sl3 = sl2.Concat(sl1);
```

The error for line 3 is
*CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable to SelectList. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Casting as follows

```
SelectList sl3 = (SelectList)sl2.Concat(sl1);
```

fails with the following error

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `<ConcatIterator>d__59-1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]` to type `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList`

What cast am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `SelectList sl3 = new SelectList(sl2.Concat(sl1));`?

Answer (score 3):

This is because [System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Concat__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) returns IEnumerable and as the error implies, it can not implicitly convert it to something it doesn't have conversion of.

Change:

```
SelectList sl3 = sl2.Concat(sl1);
```

To the following, which work, because SelectList constructor accepts `IEnumerable`

```
SelectList sl3 = new SelectList(sl2.Concat(sl1));
```

Comment: It would be much better to first get the two and then create the list instead of creating two lists that aren't used

Comment: @Orel This does not work, it returns a SelectList with SelectListItem.Text ='System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' and SelectListItem.Value = null.

Comment: @Camilio agreed, I started on this from existing code and didn't want to change anymore than I had to then it turned into....why can't I do this :>)

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectList sl3 = new SelectList(sl2.Concat(sl1));
```

returned the SelectList with

```
SelectListItem.Text ='System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'
```

and

```
SelectListItem.Value = null.

SelectList sl3 = new SelectList(sl2.Concat(sl1), "Value", "Text");
```

solved this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use .union on both SelectLists

```
    List<person> persons = new List<person>();
    persons.Add(new person() { id = 1, name = "Abel" });
    persons.Add(new person() { id = 1, name = "Joseph" });

    List<person> persons2 = new List<person>();
    persons2.Add(new person() { id = 1, name = "Stacey" });
    persons2.Add(new person() { id = 1, name = "John" });

    SelectList s1 = new SelectList(persons);
    SelectList s2 = new SelectList(persons2);
    SelectList s3 = new SelectList(s1.Union(s2));
```

Comment: Or `.AddRange` on the List: `SelectList s3 = new SelectList(s1.AddRange(s2));`